# Most optimal way to backup postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql, database-backups, postgresql-9.6

I have a medium-sized database (postgresql 9.6) with moderate traffic. The database is located on a virtual server, described as having 4cpu cores and 8192mb of ram.

Currently I am backing up the server every hour, using pg_dump on the server. This process can take some time as you'd expect, but the reason for this question is that the process eats up a lot of CPU, meaning that we're regularly seeing degraded performance throughout the day.

Our pg_dump is run like so, to generate a dump for each table individually, as well as a single dump of all tables:

```
for table in $(psql -d "XXX" -t -c "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema = 'public'");
    do pg_dump -Fc -t $table -d "XXX" > $1/$table.bak;
done;
pg_dump -Fc -d "XXX" > $1/all_tables.bak;
```

So my question is: how can I optimize the backup process? Ideally, I am looking for the most optimal process in terms of CPU.

I have tried a few things so far, such as trying to offload the dump process to another server but I'm finding limited results...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have to ask, why are you backing up your database every hour?   Also why are you backing up every table twice?    How about once a day, at night?

Comment: Why the dump per table? As you are using the custom format, you can restore a single table from that dump just as easily.

Comment: Not that this isn't really considered a "backup" but a dump. If you want to true backup, use WAL archiving or tools like pgBackRest or barman (which will have a lot less impact on the system)

Comment: I agree that dumping every hour is maybe a bit excessive, but the database is constantly changing, so it has been useful to have regular backups in the past to minimize the loss... but yeah I agree that should probably be considered further.

As for dump per table, this is because if you try and pg_restore with -t, you don't fully restore the table (constraints, indexes and so on). However, having table-specific dumps allow table-specific restoration.

I'll check out the WAL archiving suggestion, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have backup with an hourly granularity, you should probably use `pg_basebackup` and WAL archiving (or streaming, with archival from the replica) to create a physical backup, rather than pg_dump to create logical ones.  You can then use PITR to restore to almost any time point you want.  You will have to take a new basebackup occasionally to keep restore time down, but almost certainly not every hour.  Also, pg_basebackup has a low CPU load (apart from compression, but that is done on the local side not the database side if you run pg_basebackup over the network).